# one to one of multivariate function...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k $ has positive definite gradient matrix, $\dot{f}\equiv ( \partial f_i/\partial x_j )$.

Then, where can I refer to see that $f$ is 1-1 or how to prove it?

Any comments or ideas you would give could help me. :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Inverse Function Theorem?

Comment: @Travis Yes, is it helpful for this?

Comment: Since $\dot{f}$ is positive definite, it is invertible, and so $f$ is a local diffeomorphism in some neighborhood of any point.

Comment: @Travis Ok, Thank you. I'd rather get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

Locally it will be $1-1$ but globally maybe not. An example

$$(x,y) \mapsto (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$$

which is really $z \mapsto e^z$ from $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. It has period $(0, 2\pi)$ so it is not $1-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Then, what if $f(x)$ has p.d gradient matrix for each x $\in dom(f)$? Is it still impossible to be $1-1$?

Comment: No worries. There are some results that guarantee $f$ $1-1$ under local $1-1$ and some global conditions, I think $|f(x)| \to \infty$ when $|x| \to \infty$ is enough.

Comment: Oh, positive definite jacobian is interesting, I'll have to think about that.